# How to read a yml file into a java hashmap in dropwizard

Tags: java, hashmap, yaml, dropwizard

In my config.yml I have a configuration like this

```
myObject:
  key1: value1
  key2:value2
  key3: value3
```

I then have a Dropwizard Configuration class as

```
public class MyObject {

String key1;
String value1;
String key2;
.. so on

}
```

How do I read the yml file so that its read as just one hashmap? Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

You can read yaml files using jackson's objectmapper, and then give it any type you want. A very basic example for your above yaml would be:

File test_yaml.yaml:

```
myObject:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
  key3: value3
```

Code:

```
package yaml;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;

public class YamlMapParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

        InputStream resource = YamlMapParser.class.getResourceAsStream("/yaml/test_yaml.yaml");
        Map readValue = mapper.readValue(resource, Map.class);
        System.out.println(readValue);
    }
}
```

The important bit is to give Jackson's `ObjectMapper` a `YAMLFactory` to work with.

The above code then prints:

```
{myObject={key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3}}
```

I hope that helps!

Artur

Answer (score 4):

When creating a Dropwizard application, the `YourApplication` class will need to extend `Application<YourConfiguration>`. So anyway you'll need to create a `YourConfiguration` class. Now, inside the `YourConfiguration` class, if you want to avoid listing all properties and corresponding getter/setter, you can define a single property as `Map` and specify all the key-values under the previously defined property in the `yaml` file.

config.yml

```
myMap:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
```

YourConfiguration.class

```
class YourConfiguration extends Configuration {
  Map<String, String> myMap;

  Map<String, String> getConfigMap() {
    return myMap;
  }
}
```

Comment: How the same can be read from spring.xml based application?